# Replace interior of multi dimensional matrix / tensor in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 2x2 matrix, for example :

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    3    3    3    0
[3,]    0    3    3    3    0
[4,]    0    3    3    3    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I want to replace the middle part of this matrix, the threes, with a different matrix :

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  900  900  900
[2,]  900  900  900
[3,]  900  900  900
```

So that my output looks like this :

```
     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
[1,]    0    0      0      0      0
[2,]    0    900    900    900    0
[3,]    0    900    900    900    0
[4,]    0    900    900    900    0
[5,]    0    0      0      0      0
```

if `y` is a 3 by 3 matrix, and `x` is the original matrix, I get an error when I try this :

```
x[2:4, 2:4] = y
```

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Do I have to produce an index vector?

This matrix may be very large, and is part of a large calculation, so I want to save as much memory/processing time in any solution to this.

***edit***
These are all tensors and really look like this :

```
<A 3x3x1x1 dense tensor>
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  900  900  900
[2,]  900  900  900
[3,]  900  900  900
```

Comment: Your code works with your sample data

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. These are actually tensors from tensorr library

Comment: Please provide `dput(x)` and `dput(y)` to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little simpler, you can do it like so

```
m <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,
              0,3,3,3,0,
              0,3,3,3,0,
              0,3,3,3,0,
              0,0,0,0,0), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
m


m[2:4, 2:4] <- 900
m

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0  900  900  900    0
[3,]    0  900  900  900    0
[4,]    0  900  900  900    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Note that `m[2:4, 2:4] <- rep(900,9)` would also work, where `rep(900,9)` can be replaced with any vector (in this case, of length 9).

So another way could be

```
inner_matrix <- matrix(rep(900, 9),ncol=3, byrow=T)
m[2:4, 2:4] <- inner_matrix
```

For a matrix of >2 dimensions (in this case, tensors)

```
m <- array(structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 
                       0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 
                       0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L, 1L, 1L)), dim=c(5,5,1,1))
m

m[2:4,2:4,1,1] <- rep(900,9)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but I had to clarify the question because the original data is a tensor:

x[,,1,1][2:4, 2:4,,] = rep(2, 9) gives the error

Comment: @Frank those extra commas mean it's a 4 dimensional matrix, i'll edit the answer

Comment: @Frank can you please provide the output of `class(first_matrix)`

Comment: [1] "dtensor"
attr(,"package")
[1] "tensorr"

Comment: Thanks!! It works if I change the second matrix to a list using as.list().

Do you recommend me using as.list()  ?

m[2:4,2:4,1,1] <- as.list(matrix2)

Comment: @Frank I would try to keep the class (matrix, vector, list etc) as simple as you can so I would try to avoid using lists, but if converting to a list first makes it work, and it does what you're after, that's great. Just keep an eye on it as multi dimensional arrays/matrices are complicated, and lists may add more complexity

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a selector matrix to subset the region and replace it using `y` matrix as follows:

```r
my_selector <- matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, c(
  2, 2,
  2, 3,
  2, 4, 
  3,2,
  3,3,
  3,4,
  4,2,
  4,3,
  4,4
))
x[my_selector] <- y
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
x
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] 0    0    0    0    0   
# [2,] 0    900  900  900  0   
# [3,] 0    900  900  900  0   
# [4,] 0    900  900  900  0   
# [5,] 0    0    0    0    0
```

The plus side of this method of replacement is the values to subset and replace can be anywhere in the matrix, but the downside might be constructing and storing the selector matrix manually.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat more general reply to the request would be to use a logical expression inside the "[" operator used with  the assignment operator "<-":

```
m[m>0] <- 900

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0  900  900  900    0
[3,]    0  900  900  900    0
[4,]    0  900  900  900    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

There's actually only one function in play and it's name is "[<-" and it takes three arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In reality, any entry of the matrix will be a real number (positive, negative, zero).

Comment: My approach can be made much more general, but I stopped adding to it when I saw that you preferred the more restricted approach in the accepted answer.